# Embed Twitter feed AND REPLIES TO ME in a web page

Tags: twitter

I'm using the Twitter-generated "Twitter Badge" HTML and JavaScript to show my Twitter feed on a web page.  I'd like to include the replies *to me* in the same feed, or at least in another one.  (My replies to others are already in there.) One the Twitter site, I just click on the @username link on the right panel and get the #replies for my userid.  Does anybody know how to embed that in a page?  Thanks.

Comment: As of June 2013, Twitter no longer offers public JSONP feeds. You'll need to [create a widget](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines) using their tools, although you can [customize its appearance](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#customization) a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [API method](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses-mentions) that will let you pull the 20 most recent @replies in XML or JSON format; however, it requires authentication, so you'll want to do this on the backend. (There are OAuth libraries for Javascript, but that doesn't sound especially workable to me for this use case.)

Comment: The link to the API method is broken, could you please update it.

Answer (score 2):

The reply link suggested by @Meredith is removed from twitter. Anyone else have a better solution ?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use twitter regularly enough to have tweets in search(expires after sometime), you could use twitter searches jsonp.

I wrote a simple js lib around it. http://gist.github.com/110884

That will give you an array of matching tweets that you can then style or whatever.

```
//done up in no framework js
Twitter.search({q:"alan",
  callback:function(results){
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
    {
      alert(results[i].text)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Juitter - jQuery Plugin](http://juitter.com/) for Twitter?

Comment: No.  Thanks; I'll check that out immediately.

Comment: Like @BaroqueBobcat's suggestion, Juitter -- which is pretty cool, I must say -- relies on search.  I was looking for direct timeline data: tweets by a given user id (me) and all the @replies to it.  That way the data persists longer than in search.  I think I shall have to write something myself using the API.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to embed any content from an external page (including tweets) is to use the following code:

```
<?php
 echo "<html><head>";
 echo "<style> body { background: #FBFAF9; font-family: sans-serif; }";
 echo "h4 {text-transform:capitalize; font-family: sans-serif;} h5 {text-transform:capitalize; font-family: sans-serif; color: grey; } </style>";
 echo "</head><body>";


 $data = file_get_contents('https://twitter.com/your_feed_here');

 $data = explode("<div class=\"stream profile-stream\">", $data);
 $data = explode("<div class=\"grid hidden\">", $data[1]);
 $data = str_replace("</p>", "</p>", $data[0]);
 $data = explode("\n", $data);

 foreach ($data as $line) { 

$date = explode("data-long-form=\"true\">", $line);
$date = explode("</span>", $date[1]);
$article['date'] = $date[0];


$title = explode("<p class=\"js-tweet-text tweet-text\">", $line);
$title = explode("</p>", $title[1]);
$article['title'] = $title[0];


$articles[] = $article;
 }

 unset($articles[0]);
 unset($articles[count($articles)]);

 foreach ($articles as $markup) :
 ?>
 <div class="entry">
<h5><?=$markup['date'];?></h5>
<div style="width:270px"><?=$markup['title']?></div>
 </div> 
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```